# Why is parentNode defunct in the javascript DOM for Attr (Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE)?

Tags: javascript, dom

In the javascript DOM, the class Attr extends Node, of nodeType == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE. This is great. The Node.prototype has the parentNode property, which is some getter "get parentNode" function with body I cannot inspect (on Chrome). But for Attr the parentNode always returns null, and it cannot be assigned either.

I would like to know why that is? Did they expect that Attr objects would be reused and shared between different nodes?

Here I am showing a Chrome console dialog:

```
$0
    <section code=​"123" foo=​"bar">​…​</section>​
$0.attributes[0]
    code=​"123"
$0.attributes[0].parentNode
    null
$0.attributes[0].parentNode = $0
    <section code=​"123" foo=​"bar">​…​</section>​
$0.attributes[0].parentNode
    null
Object.defineProperty(Attr.prototype, 'parentNode', { writable: true, value: null });
    Attr {…}
$0.attributes[0].parentNode
    null
$0.attributes[0].parentNode = $0
    <section code=​"123" foo=​"bar">​…​</section>​
$0.attributes[0].parentNode
    <section code=​"123" foo=​"bar">​…​</section>​
```

Now whether attributes are reused?

```
s = $0.cloneNode(false)
    <section code=​"123" foo=​"bar">​</section>​
s.attributes[0] == $0.attributes[0]
    false
s.attributes.removeNamedItem('code')
    code=​"123"
s.attributes.removeNamedItem('foo')
    foo=​"bar"
s
    <section>​</section>​
s.attributes.setNamedItem($0.attributes[0])
    Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setNamedItem' on 'NamedNodeMap': The node provided is an attribute node that is already an attribute of another Element; attribute nodes must be explicitly cloned.

s.attributes.setNamedItem($0.attributes[0].cloneNode())
    null
s
    <section code=​"123">​</section>​
```

So it seems clear that Attr is not supposed to be shared between different elements. Therefore, I don't understand why parentNode property was decided to leave defunct for Attr nodes?

I can probably make my own workarounds, by overriding the Node property with one specific for Attr, but still, why?

What to know a use-case? Well, how about implementing XSLT on javascript, in XSLT you can inquire the parent of an attribute, which is often quite important.

Comment: I would guess that's the way it is defined in the ECMAscript standard. If you are really interested in getting an answer on this, I suggest that you try to look for historic discussions with ECMAscript on this.

Comment: @ControlAltDel - The ECMAScript standard doesn't define anything related to the DOM. That's what the *DOM* standard is for. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're making me look DOM (heh heh heh HEH HEH HEH!)

Comment: @ControlAltDel - 

Answer (score 1):

According to [the specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-attr%E2%91%A0):

> **Note:**
>
> `Attr` nodes participate in a tree for historical reasons; they never have a (non-null) parent or any children and are therefore alone in a tree.

So, Chrome is following spec there. `Attr` elements never have a non-`null` `parentNode`.

It's always dangerous to ask "why" questions because without being able to cite the specific meeting notes where a decision is made, the answer is going to be a matter of opinion.

But the DOM spec is clear that the original design of `Attr` was a mistake, [for instance](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-attr):

> Attr nodes are simply known as attributes. They are sometimes referred to as *content* attributes to avoid confusion with *IDL* attributes.
>
> Attributes have a namespace (null or a non-empty string), namespace prefix (null or a non-empty string), local name (a non-empty string), value (a string), and element (null or an element).
>
> **Note:**
>
> If designed today they would just have a name and value. ☹

This seems to be just one way in which the design doesn't necessarily make great sense.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was just trying to figure out how I can fix this design mistake. And I found on Chrome that there is (now?) the Attr.prototype.ownerElement property. Why that isn't simply parentElement (or parentNode), is probably another indicator that the DOM specification was sloppily thrown together and perhaps the people involved didn't really know what they were doing.

So in short the functionality exists, they just gave that a different name.

Comment: It's pretty well known that the original DOM specification was compromise made for compatibility with previous specification, implementations and various interest groups. That resulted in a range of non-ideal choices. If you ever watched specifications being developed, it's clear that choices are often made on what everyone "can live with" than what is the best technical solution. DOM was undoubtedly like that.

Comment: FWIW, the ownerElement property of Attr objects was added in DOM 2, which became a W3C Recommendation in 2000.